# Eliminar parte de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, api

Hola amigos tengo un problema con un array obtenido por una api, me la devuelve de la siguiente manera:

```json
{"setEventosComercios":[
{"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">Se intenta contactar comercio para informar que tienen cheques por retirar, pero no contestan los numeros de contacto. Virginia <\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
{"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">Se informa que el dia lunes 14/9 pueden retirar cheques pendientes. Virginia <\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
{"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">visita para INFORMAR NUEVO PLAN 241 con 3 cierres-Atendido por Beatriz de Laciar-Explico en detalle operatoria y condiciones-Dejo copia-MARIO.<\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
}]
```

Lo que necesito es obtener es el texto que esta dentro de las etiquetas y eliminar u ocultar lo demás , como puedo hacerlo?
las etiquetas a eliminar son :
al contenido de la api lo obtengo de javascript de la siguiente manera:

-al inicio:

```
{"setEventosComercios":[
{"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">
```

-final:

```
<\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>
```

```
for(info of this.respuestaAgenda.setEventosComercios){
//  var remover= this.agendaComentarios.splice(1,1);
//  console.log(remover)
    this.agendaInsertar={
      fecha      : fechaAgenda1,
      descripcion: this.agendaDescripcion,
      comentarios: this.agendaComentarios,
      operador   : this.nombreOperador}
      this.contenidoAgenda.push(this.agendaInsertar)
    }
```

editado

Comment: No entiendo donde está el array

Comment: el array es todo esto=> { <TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">texto importante que necesito obtener.</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT> }

Comment: Pero eso no tiene forma de arreglo, te recomiendo que leas esta documentacion https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Agrega la respuesta de la api tal cual la recibes, no le saques nada, porque eso que colocaste no es un arreglo de javascript

Comment: Por favor agregala en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Haz click aqui para [edit] Si necesitas ayuda para formular la pregunta lee [ask] y tambien te recomiendo que leas [example]

Comment: Ahora si, eso es un JSON correcto, recuerda actualizar la pregunta para que se entienda qué es lo que necesitas. Por favor lee como crear un [example] asi tu pregunta es bien recibida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como referencia la pregunta principal (hacer match con el texto que se encuentra entre las etiquetas `<FONT></FONT>`) y que es algo similar a lo que se cuestiona en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7167279/7927192) en el sitio en inglés, puedes utilizar la siguiente regex: `(?<=(<FONT[^>]*>))(.|\n)*?(?=(<\/FONT>))` la cual es una combinación de:

- [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880892/7927192) que obtiene todo el texto entre ambas etiquetas (`(.|\n)*?`)
- [Esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40908001/7927192) que indica que el texto debe estar entre `<FONT>` y `</FONT>` (`(?<=(<FONT))` `(?=(<\/FONT>))`) y adicionalmente "guarda el match" de estos dos valores por aparte
- Y esta [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33656025/7927192) que ayuda a hacer el match cuando las etiquetas contienen atributos (`(?<=(<FONT[^>]*>))`), ya que si utilizas la regex del punto anterior tal cual está, no funcionaría ya que la etiqueta font tiene atributos que no coincidirían para hacer el match.

```js
const response = {
"setEventosComercios":[
  {"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">Se intenta contactar comercio para informar que tienen cheques por retirar, pero no contestan los numeros de contacto. Virginia <\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
  {"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">Se informa que el dia lunes 14/9 pueden retirar cheques pendientes. Virginia <\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
  {"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">visita para INFORMAR NUEVO PLAN 241 con 3 cierres-Atendido por Beatriz de Laciar-Explico en detalle operatoria y condiciones-Dejo copia-MARIO.<\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
]}

response.setEventosComercios.forEach(comentario => {
  const regex = /(?<=(<FONT[^>]*>))(.|\n)*?(?=(<\/FONT>))/
  console.log(comentario.comentario.match(regex))
});
```

Como puedes observar en el ejemplo, lo anterior devolverá en un array las coincidencias para cada grupo especificado (aún puedes refinar la regex para evitar que tome el último caracter como otro grupo), tanto para el texto como las etiquetas en cuestión, por lo que restaría reasignar ese valor para tenerlo limpio.

```js
const response = {
"setEventosComercios":[
  {"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">Se intenta contactar comercio para informar que tienen cheques por retirar, pero no contestan los numeros de contacto. Virginia <\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
  {"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">Se informa que el dia lunes 14/9 pueden retirar cheques pendientes. Virginia <\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
  {"comentario":"<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2\"><P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"10\" COLOR=\"#0B333C\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\">visita para INFORMAR NUEVO PLAN 241 con 3 cierres-Atendido por Beatriz de Laciar-Explico en detalle operatoria y condiciones-Dejo copia-MARIO.<\/FONT><\/P><\/TEXTFORMAT>"},
]}

response.setEventosComercios.forEach(comentario => {
  const regex = /(?<=(<FONT[^>]*>))(.|\n)*?(?=(<\/FONT>))/;
  comentario.comentario = comentario.comentario.match(regex)[0];
});

console.log(response);
```

Comment: muchas gracias era eso lo que estaba buscando hacer :D